# How to get the text from input field in Robot Framework?

Tags: selenium, automation, robotframework

[image]

I tried to get the attribute for this as -

```
 @{locator2}=     Get Webelements     //*[@class='ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid']/div/input
 ${SSOInputDatalist}=       Create List
 FOR   ${locator}   IN    @{locator2}
       ${inputs}=   get element attribute    ${locator}
       Append To List  ${SSOInputDatalist}  ${inputs}
 END
```

Every time it failed and returns Keyword `SeleniumLibrary.Get Element Attribute' expected 2 arguments, got 1`.

Comment: Read the documentation of the keyword.

Comment: Imagine we're talking and you say, "Get element attribute."; the natural question is "OK, which one?" :) So is the keyword - it expects two arguments, the element and which attribute. For your case it is `value`. [RTM](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html)

Comment: Please read the [mcve] and follow that in every post. don't add the screenshot of the html code. no one will write that for you by looking at image. Think about the persons time who answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using not correct.

```
Get Element Attribute    locator   attribute  

${input_value}   get element attribute    ${locator}      value
${input_name}   get element attribute     ${locator}      name
```